# google chart API: set table column width to fit data

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a table that I created using gviz_api. I would like for each column to automatically resize it's width so that the width of the column nicely fits whatever content is there. For example, currently I have a table that looks something like this:

```
  Num column    |  Num column     |   String column               |
1234            |           1234  |  some string                  |
```

and I would like it to look like this:

```
Num column |  Num column |   String column |
1234       |        1234 | some string     |
```

Is there a property I can set for the entire table to do this? Or do I have to go through each cell individually and set the width explicitly to some number?

Thanks.

Comment: I like this question but I feel there is no easy answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I was dealing with the same issue, here is what I did for my project and it worked out well. I'm not saying it will work %100 but its worth a shot.

```
chart: {
   type: 'TABLE',
   options: {width: '100%', chartArea:{left:0,top:0,width:"100%",height:"100%"}} /* THIS LINE */
}
```

You may have used different code than I did to generate your chart. But somewhere you probably have an area to input some options. That is where I would put the line I labeled /* THIS LINE */.

If you paste your code, I may be able to help better.